# Setting up Mac VPN on simple network with separate IPs

Tags: vpn, router, mac, mac-osx

We have a pretty simple network configuration. A typical ASDL line with two extra IP addresses. We have a basic home network router Dlink DIR-655. We have two Mac OS X Snow Leopard Servers that we want to setup VPN on. The problem is that we can't change the ports which VPN works under ie. we can only setup port forwarding for UDP 500,1701,4500 to a single server.

I'm wondering how we can cost effectively re-work our network so that we can take advantage of the separate IP addresses and have both VPNs working with the same router. Is that possible with our current hardware setup or do we need something more powerful?

We're also toying with Mobile Access and wondering if that might be easier to setup.

Expert help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand it correctly that you have *one* ADSL line, which is accessible via at least two IP addresses at the same time, which can't be separated by your router, so it doesn't make any difference for it if the connections goes to IP A or IP B?

In this case, I guess you need a better router (or better software for the one you have), which allows you to create an alias ethernet interface for the WAN side PPPOE port and then allows you to create different forwarding rules for these two interfaces. I could imagine that OpenWRT or DDWRT for Linksys WRT54G-L like devices would offer such capabilities, but I never tried that, due to the lack of more than one public IP adresss at my DSL line :)